# Can I turn this into a pivot table?

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, sql

I have the following query:

```
select q.description question,
group_concat(a.description) answers
from answer a
join question q on a.question_id = q.id
where survey_id = 6
group by q.id
```

It gives me a result that looks something like this:

```
question             answers
Do you like cats?    Yes,Yes,No,Yes
Do you like pizza?   Yes,Yes,Yes,No
```

Is there any way I can get something more like this?

```
question             answer1 answer2 answer3 answer4
Do you like cats?    Yes     Yes     No      Yes
Do you like pizza?   Yes     Yes     Yes     No
```

Comment: Probably no. Is there a fixed amount of answers?

Comment: What's the framework etc. from which you access mysql? However, I don't understand the purpose to output raw survey data (not aggregated). Do you have only 4 participants?

Comment: probably no ... unless break each answer using sub-query

Comment: No, there's not a fixed amount of answers. I'm using symfony (PHP) but I was hoping to achieve this within SQL. If I want to do it in PHP, I already know how to do that, but it's a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but needs dynamic SQL;

You can see a related solution that can be extended to your problem here: [Pivots with Dynamic Columns in SQL Server 2005](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx)

Reproduced in part below, since I think it is very cool:

---

This query works both on SQL Server 2000 and 2005. It is efficient, but some may not like it because it uses the same variable (@cols) on both sides of an assignment. Another solution that works on SQL Server 2005 only is to use XML PATH.

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000)
SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT
                                '],[' + t2.ColName
                        FROM    Table1 AS t2
                        ORDER BY '],[' + t2.ColName
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                      ), 1, 2, '') + ']'
```

This column list is used twice in the pivot query that we aim to construct. Once it is use in the list of columns that we want to retrieve, and once it is used as the list of values that should become columns. Having constructed this list of columns above, we can just concatenate it with the missing parts of the pivot query like:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @query = N'SELECT tID, '+
@cols +'
FROM
(SELECT  t2.tID
      , t1.ColName
      , t2.Txt
FROM    Table1 AS t1
        JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.ColId = t2.ColID) p
PIVOT
(
MAX([Txt])
FOR ColName IN
( '+
@cols +' )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY tID;'
```

Executing this with

```
EXECUTE(@query)
```

will give us the expected result: a table that is pivoted and shows columns that were specified in a table:

```
tID         Country    Day        Month
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1           US         4          July
2           US         11         Sep
3           US         25         Dec
```